Getting 401 Unauthorized error when attempting to POST to ASP.NET with Powershell
With the recent shenanigans of Crowd Strike, we have developed a tool to automatically unlock bitlocker-protected drives using a live USB. We have two MBAM servers, a production server and one server that is legacy. Keeping code previews short for brevity.
Fetching keys from the prod server was easy enough, it takes a single request authorized with a service account
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://XXXXX/xx/xx?serialNumber=$id" -Credential $Cred -UseBasicParsing
The legacy server is the problem, it is ASP.NET on IIS 8.5.
I have copied the headers and form data from the browsers dev tools. It seems like I need Windows credentials, event validators, and a session cookie. I get a WWW-Authenticate header from the server, but it is not used in browser requests.
I am able to successfully login to the server using credentials
Invoke-WebRequest -URI $MBAM_URL -Credential $UserCredential -Method GET
Getting the ASP validators was easy enough
switch ($input.name)
{
    "__LASTFOCUS" { $SearchData["__LASTFOCUS"] = $input.value }
    "__VIEWSTATE" { $SearchData["__VIEWSTATE"] = $input.value }
    "__EVENTARGUMENT" { $SearchData["__EVENTARGUMENT"] = $input.value }
    "__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" { $SearchData["__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"] = $input.value }
    "__EVENTVALIDATION" { $SearchData["__EVENTVALIDATION"] = $input.value }
}

As well as setting my session cookie
$SearchHeaders["Cookie"] = $request.Headers["Set-Cookie"].Split(";")[0]
Using this configuration plus the form data, I am able to craft and identical request to my browser.
The issue comes from actually trying to retrieve the key from the server
Invoke-WebRequest -URI $MBAM_URL -Method POST -Body $body -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Headers $SearchHeaders -Credential $UserCredential
This request returns a 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. error on every run.
I've tried messing with the authentication and logic the best I could. I rewrote this program in Python to test on working machines, but still get the same 401 error when attempting to POST to the server and fetch the key.
I've tried removing credentials, adding the WWW-Authentication header to the request, only authenticating using cookies, using a service account, etc.
Maybe there is something I am missing with ASP.NET, as I really don't think my programming logic is the issue. I have a similar script that interacts with an ASP.NET server for inventory cataloging that works perfectly.

Hum, you might have to look at the actual server side code used for the logon. It's possible that some session() values are set, and they are 100% server side. So on our main page, there is a logon link, and if the referring URL is not valid, we don't process the logon attempt.  (we don't allow jumping to logon page without a valid referring URL). On page load, often some session() values are set, and if they are not correctly set, then again we don't process the logon request.  So, rather difficult to troubleshoot here without you posting the server logon code (code behind) being used here

Do you know if these session() values are able to be used in a keep-alive client? Thanks for the comment, i'll try using persistent sessions. I too wish I was able to share the logic of the servers logon.

I not sure you have any choice in the matter from client side code to preserve 100% server side code variables that are being persisted by session().  So, sure, if some client side software pings the server, or calls some web method, that would in theory keep the session() values alive, but we talking about a usual default of 20 minutes, and a simple logon attempt thus not going to care or worry about some client  keepalive code that pings server every so often to prevent 20 minute session() variables timeout. As I stated, this is 100% server side code - not at all client side code anyway.

So, none of the variables in the compiled server side code in session() has anything to do with client side code, and no, such code behind variables from session() are not in any way available from client side code - kind of the whole idea as to how asp.net works. So, often on a page load, a bunch of code runs, and for that code to "persist" the variables in that compiled code, then 100% server side session() is often used.  So, while ViewState() is cached client side (but encrypted), session() values never travel to the client side, nor are they available or exposed to any client side code

You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 401 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.
